# Persist instantiated XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, persistence

I have a quite large application which serializes ~100 of different classes into XML.
Since it takes some time to create the XML serializer at runtime, I'm doing this for the most important classes while the application is loading. For the other ones, when needed.

In order to improve the performance I was thinking about somehow persist the created serializer.

While I was googling that issue I found a way with the Microsoft tool "sgen.exe". It allows you to create a assembly which, as far as I understood, holds all serializer to types which are in a specified assembly.

When trying to do that for my assemblies I recognized that all assemblies (and all which are used by it) needed to be signed. Before I go ahead and create a lot signing files and start to do that for all the projects I just want to make sure that I'm not missing anything.

So finally here is my question:
Is that the way to go if I want to have my XML serializer to be available before the application is running?

I guess storing them in a dll is "the only way" but the way they it is created seems very intricate to me. Can't I just somehow binary serialize let's say a list of all types of serializer (List) I need, load them on startup and finally tell the framework to use them instead?

Regards

Comment: Be careful with signing, once you sign your assembly *all* the other assemblies you use **must** also be signed.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that instantiating the serializer is the bottleneck of your app? I'd suspect the serializing process itself would be a more time consuming action.

Comment: No, it's certainly not, but it's one point of many I'd like to improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating serializers is indeed slow. It should be no surprise: after all creating a serializer means reflecting over your types and generating (IL) code at runtime. Using sgen is the way to go: it does the same thing but does it at build time, storing that code in an assembly on disk, so that it doesn't have to be generated at runtime.

You cannot serialize the serializer's code with binary serialization (which can be used for *data*, not for code). Well, in fact, code can of course be stored on disk, in an assembly, and that's exactly what sgen will do for you.

It is a good idea to sign the assembly containing the serializable types, but that does not mean that *all* your assemblies need to be signed. Just put the serializable types in a separate dll, and sign that one only.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess there is no other way? Refactoring all that data classes into another project is going to be very extensive...